# Можно ли установить debian 7 в 2023?

Tags: linux, debian

Мне просто неоходимо установить Debian 7. Я знаю, что он не имеет LTS. Но всё же может как-нибудь можно установить. Потому что сейчас, как только дохожу до пункта выбора зеркал, никакое из списка не подходит, вылетает ошибка. Делаю всё в коробке(Visual Box 7.0.10)

Comment: http://archive.debian.org/debian/README

Comment: Что мешает скачать образ с сайта или торрента и установить? https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/7.11.0/amd64/iso-cd/

Comment: @void а вы прочитайте вопрос внимательнее и увидите что мешает

Comment: @andreymal, ну так я и предлагаю скачать, а не подкачивать из мастера Virtual Box.

Comment: @void в мастере нет никакого «пункта выбора зеркал»

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. А тогда в чем суть вопроса? Может, я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: @void а вы попробуйте сами установить и сразу увидите в чём суть вопроса)

Comment: Хотя если автор по какой-то причине не смог пропустить «пункт выбора зеркал», то это создаёт подозрение, что он зачем-то взял netinst-образ

Comment: Понятно. Установщик не видит зеркал для подкачки пакетов и продолжения установки. Я просто расценил вопрос как проблему скачать сам iso Debian 7.

Comment: @andreymal Не, я взял не netinst-образ. Пропускал, но там сильно урезается функционал. Там даже выскакивает предупреждение, когда пропускаешь выбор зеркал.

Comment: @Kriforce на функционал можно плевать, всё можно донастроить после установки и подключения архивного репозитория (см. первый комментарий)

Comment: Да, всё получилось, спасибо.

Comment: Дивидишки распаковать и скормить как зеркало не сложно